# popularity of guns depending on the level

Tags: sql, database, data-analysis

| id | level | gun_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xxxx |
| 3 | 1 | xxxx |
| 2 | 1 | yyyy |
| 3 | 2 | zzzz |
| 1 | 2 | zzzz |
| 2 | 2 | xxxx |

should display a table:

| level | popular_gun_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxxx |
| 2 | zzzz |

I am new to sql please help

Comment: Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [No attempt made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), show us your current attempt, explain what is not working and what you need help with.

Comment: what should happnbe if xxxx and zzzz have the same number of occurrences

Comment: I have a large database, I think this can not be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataabse support CTE and window function you could do

```
WITH CTE AS(
SELECT level,   gun_name , COUNT(*) num_ber
FROM table1
GROUP BY level,     gun_name),
CTE2 As (
SELECT level,gun_name,Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY level ORDEr BY num_ber DESC) rn
FROM CTE)
SELECT
  level, gun_name
FROM CTE2 WHERE rn = 1
```